# Change Python Poetry initializing new project with undesired pyproject.toml authors

Tags: python, packaging, author

When I initialize a Python project using

```
poetry new <name>
```

I find in the * pyproject.toml* an undesired author by default. How can I change this author?

Comment: It looks like poetry is getting it from your Git Config (whatever you set your name and email to be in Git) https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/blob/863e27140f6638d1510562318ae9e7fb6bbd7d2a/poetry/console/commands/new.py#L51

Comment: The account that appears in the pyproject.toml is one I have recently used on a private GitLab server. Any idea how can I solve?

Comment: you have probably found the answer by now, but i just came across the same issue an solved it by changing my git config. i will add it as an answer

Answer (score 2):

to solve this issue change the git config info. navigate to a specific project or just do it globally.

```
git config --list
```

you should now see your user name and email address. change them using the following commands.

```
git config --global user.name 'your user name'
git config --global user.email 'your email address'
```